# Binding 2 trackbars to an int throwing an ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, trackbar

I have a Form that looks like the Find form on Notepad++. There is a tabControl with 2 tabs. Each tab has a trackbar and I want the value of each trackbar to be the same, if somebody moves trackbar1 then trackbar2 moves automatically.

Find form constructor

```
private NotifyInt transparencyPercent;
public FindForm(string text, Action<String> findTextAction)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    transparencyPercent = new NotifyInt(85);
    this.findTransparencyTrack.DataBindings.Add("Value",transparencyPercent, "IntValue");
    this.findReplaceTransparencyTrack.DataBindings.Add("Value",transparencyPercent, "IntValue");

}
```

NotifyInt class

```
public class NotifyInt : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public NotifyInt(int initialValue)
    {
        this.IntValue = initialValue;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IntValue"));
    }
    public int IntValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.intValue;

        }
        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting: " + value);
            this.intValue = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IntValue"));

        }
    }
}
```

Designer Settings

```
// 
// findTransparencyTrack
// 
this.findTransparencyTrack.AutoSize = false;
this.findTransparencyTrack.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
this.findTransparencyTrack.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 52);
this.findTransparencyTrack.Maximum = 100;
this.findTransparencyTrack.Minimum = 5;
this.findTransparencyTrack.Name = "findTransparencyTrack";
this.findTransparencyTrack.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 13);
this.findTransparencyTrack.TabIndex = 2;
this.findTransparencyTrack.TickStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TickStyle.None;
this.findTransparencyTrack.Value = 5;
this.findTransparencyTrack.ValueChanged += new    System.EventHandler(this.findTransparencyTrack_ValueChanged);
// 
// findReplaceTransparencyTrack
// 
this.findReplaceTransparencyTrack.AutoSize = false;    
this.findReplaceTransparencyTrack.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
this.findReplaceTransparencyTrack.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 52);
this.findReplaceTransparencyTrack.Maximum = 100;
this.findReplaceTransparencyTrack.Minimum = 5;
this.findReplaceTransparencyTrack.Name = "findReplaceTransparencyTrack";
this.findReplaceTransparencyTrack.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 13);
this.findReplaceTransparencyTrack.TabIndex = 2;
this.findReplaceTransparencyTrack.TickStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TickStyle.None;
this.findReplaceTransparencyTrack.Value = 5;
this.findReplaceTransparencyTrack.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.findReplaceTransparencyTrack_ValueChanged);
```

If I open the form, slide the trackbar on the find tab and focus on another control Visual studio pops up an error saying

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Value of '0' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be
>   between 'Minimum' and 'Maximum'.

on the bracket at the end of the NotifyInt setter even though the output only shows the value to be 85 & 75.
Setting: 85
Setting: 75

If I open the form, click on the second tab and then back to the first tab and move the slider on the first tab everything is fine and there are no errors.